# Mrbayes stop at certain generation without error

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny

I am using Mrbayes v 3.2.7 MPI version to infer phylogeny, and I set the ngeneration to 10,000,000, but it often stop at certain generation (usually far smaller than given generations). Even if I restart the analysis by invoking the `append=yes` , but it stops again.

Anyone have this problem? I would appreciate you for sharing your useful experience.

Best regards,

Yanpeng

**Version info**

```
Version:   3.2.7
Features:  SSE AVX FMA Beagle readline
Host type: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (CPU: x86_64)
Compiler:  gnu 7.5.0
```

**Command line:**

```
nohup mpirun -np 8 mb-mpi concatenate_phylipID.nex < /dev/null > /dev/null &
```

Mrbayes block in nexus file:

```
begin mrbayes;

    outgroup t1;

    charset Subset1 = 1-373 1953-2032;
    charset Subset2 = 374-531;
    charset Subset3 = 532-677 1583-1618;
    charset Subset4 = 678-1442;
    charset Subset5 = 1443-1582 1619-1725;
    charset Subset6 = 1726-1802 1803-1952;
    charset Subset7 = 2033-2661;

    partition PartitionFinder = 7:Subset1, Subset2, Subset3, Subset4, Subset5, Subset6, Subset7;
    set partition=PartitionFinder;

    lset applyto=(1) nst=6 rates=invgamma;
    lset applyto=(2) nst=6 rates=invgamma;
    prset applyto=(2) statefreqpr=fixed(equal);
    lset applyto=(3) nst=6 rates=invgamma;
    lset applyto=(4) nst=6 rates=invgamma;
    lset applyto=(5) nst=6 rates=invgamma;
    lset applyto=(6) nst=6 rates=gamma;
    lset applyto=(7) nst=6 rates=invgamma;

    prset applyto=(all) ratepr=variable;
    unlink statefreq=(all) revmat=(all) shape=(all) pinvar=(all) tratio=(all);
    mcmc nchains = 4 ngen = 10000000 samplefreq = 10000 printfreq = 10000 diagnfreq = 10000;
    sump;
    sumt;
    quit;
end;
```

Comment: How are you deciding it has stopped prior to 10,000,000 generations? Is it by counting the number of samples?

Comment: Check the log file,  It tells you how many generations have been done.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a screen or similar to see if it is something weird with nohup?

Comment: I prefer running prpgroms background if the analysis will take a long time. I think you are right. Ever I run it in PC five days, it works. Thanks.